# gimbal FYXVisitManager startWithOptions:options

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, gimbal

I have this problem with Gimbal framework:
when I try to start the FYXVisitManager with options, the system don't call the delgate method:
I initialize the object with these rows of code:

```
self.visitManager = [[FYXVisitManager alloc] init];
self.visitManager.delegate = self;
NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-40] forKey:FYXVisitOptionArrivalRSSIKey];
[options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-75] forKey:FYXVisitOptionDepartureRSSIKey];
[self.visitManager startWithOptions:options];
```

Answer (score 0):

For proper working you must :-

1. implement FYXServiceDelegate and FYXVisitDelegate protocol to your class and set the delegate
2. `[FYX disableLocationUpdates];
   [FYX setAppId:@"your_app_id"
        appSecret:@"your_app_secret"
        callbackUrl:@"your_callback_url"];
   [FYX startService:self];`
3. now put your code in method `-(void)serviceStarted{}` and add this code before your code `NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [options setObject:[NSString stringWithString:FYXHighAccuracyLocation] forKey:FYXLocationModeKey];
   [FYX enableLocationUpdatesWithOptions:options];`

   P.S. :- this must be done in appdelegate if you want to work with background processing